# CSS Transition ignored via JavaScript element.style.width

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to smooth out a progress bar animation when I set the new width using, as an example, `document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.width = '20%'` but it just updates to the new width instantly instead of following the transition.  I was expecting the width to animate to the new value, perhaps I'm missing something obvious or have a basic misunderstanding of the transition property. Here's the element, advice appreciated:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#mydiv').style.width = '20%';
}, 500);
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0.4rem;
  background: orange;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your snippet, after half a second wait your orange bar expands over 1 second. Can you explain a bit more what the problem is?

Comment: Doh! See my answer (oops).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 timing functions in the `transition` property: `linear` and `ease-out.` See here for the shorthand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: What they said ^.  If you look at `#mydiv` in the Devtools, you'll probably see the `transition` property struck through because it's invalid.

Comment: That was just a type-o in my post, fixed.  So what I'm attempting should work?

Comment: It looks fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

It's working, I was repainting the div so the transition had no basis.

Refactored accordingly and it works fine.

Thanks everybody for chiming in and getting me to the issue.